# Modify a pandas DataFrame in a groupby operation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following situation I have a DataFrame composed of several DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['01/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '02/01/2023'], 
    'name': ['DE_STC', 'DE_STC','FR_STC', 'FR_STC'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Now, I want to add the values of another DataFrame to it several times (for example), based on the name.

```
# the df to be added
df_fr_stc = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['01/01/2023', '02/01/2023'], 
    'value': [-1, -1]}) 

df = df.groupby('name')

for i in range (3):
    df_temp = df.get_group('DE_STC')
    df_temp = pd.concat([df_temp, df_fr_stc], sort=False).groupby(['time']).sum().reset_index()
```

Now the problem is that I want to modify a DataFrame inside the initial df which is grouped by the 'name'.

Something like a set_group() to replace the specific DataFrame with the newly created DataFrame :

```
    df.set_group (pd.concat([df.get_group('FR_STC'), df_fr_stc], sort=False).groupby(['time']).sum().reset_index())
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Final result :

```
> df
time    name  value
0  01/01/2023  DE_STC      1
1  02/01/2023  DE_STC      2
2  01/01/2023  FR_STC      3
3  02/01/2023  FR_STC      4

> df_fr_stc
time  value
0  01/01/2023     -1
1  02/01/2023     -1

> # df + 3 x df_fr_stc
> df
time    name  value
0  01/01/2023  DE_STC      1
1  02/01/2023  DE_STC      2
2  01/01/2023  FR_STC      0
3  02/01/2023  FR_STC      1
```

---

### EDIT 1

As it seems it is unclear I will post here my initial task.

I have a dataframe like the following :

```
> df
      time                 name        value
0     01/01/2023 00:00:00  DE_STC      1
1     01/01/2023 01:00:00  DE_STC      1
...
8759  31/12/2023 23:00:00  DE_STC      1
8760  01/01/2023 00:00:00  FR_STC      2
8761  01/01/2023 01:00:00  FR_STC      2
...
17519 31/12/2023 23:00:00  FR_STC      2
...
```

Then let's say i have orders, meaning operations where I need to add 3 to all the DE_STC data in my dataframe. Another example would be to add an order for 2023 for FR_STC to add for each hour in the year the value 7.

```
> df_fr_stc
      time                 name        value
0     01/01/2023 00:00:00  FR_STC      7
1     01/01/2023 01:00:00  FR_STC      7
...
8759  31/12/2023 23:00:00  FR_STC      7


> df_de_stc
      time                 name        value
0     01/01/2023 00:00:00  DE_STC      3
1     01/01/2023 01:00:00  DE_STC      3
...
8759  31/12/2023 23:00:00  DE_STC      3
```

So first, I need to create a dataframe with a daily distribution for year 2023:

```
for i in df_orders:    
    dt_start = i[29]
    dt_end = i[28] - timedelta(hours=1)

    dti = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_end, freq='H').to_pydatetime() # just specify hourly frequency... 
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(dti, columns=['time'])

    df['value'] = i[12] # adding column with constant value
    
    # the problematic operation ?
    df_op_test.get_group(order_group) = pd.concat([df_op_test.get_group(order_group), df], sort=False).groupby(['time']).sum().reset_index()
```

So it will look like finally :

```
> df
      time                 name        value
0     01/01/2023 00:00:00  DE_STC      4
1     01/01/2023 01:00:00  DE_STC      4
...
8759  31/12/2023 23:00:00  DE_STC      4
8760  01/01/2023 00:00:00  FR_STC      9
8761  01/01/2023 01:00:00  FR_STC      9
...
17519 31/12/2023 23:00:00  FR_STC      9
...
```

What i tried above was to show with a minimalistic example what I wanted.

Comment: your question is unclear, can you explain what you want to do without using your code? Anyway using `concat` in a loop is inefficient so better find another approach.

Comment: Also why do you have `range(3)`?

Comment: I have an initial df which is composed of multiple dfs which can be grouped by their 'name' field. Then I have multiple dfs that i want to add to this initial df, like df_fr_stc, df_de_stc, etc. Then I want to sum the values of these dfs to the initial corresponding section in the original df. So the values of df_fr_stc will only be added to the initial df where the name = 'FR_STC' and the values of the df_de_stc will only be added to the initial df where the name = 'DE_STC'.

Comment: ok then my second approach below should work. You didn't comment on the `range(3)`, do you want to subtract 3 times the sum?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm checking it right now. The `range (3)` was to show I have a loop where I could have to perform several operations and thus the performance would be very important.

Comment: Then you should explain what those operations are

Comment: In my last EDIT I do explain and give an example. I'm not sure how clear it is ...

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess what you want to do from your code, you seem to have a factor `N`, which you want to use to subtract a subdataframe from your original DataFrame:

```
N = 3
s = df[['time', 'name']].merge(df_fr_stc.assign(name='FR_STC'), how='left'
                               )['value']
df['value'] += s.fillna(0, downcast='infer').mul(N)
```

For a more generic approach if you want to handle several replacement at once use a dictionary of `{'name1': sub_dataframe1, 'name2': sub_dataframe2}'`:

```
N = 3
s = df[['time', 'name']].merge(pd.concat({'FR_STC': df_fr_stc}, names=['name'])
                                 .reset_index(level=0), how='left'
                              )['value']
df['value'] += s.fillna(0, downcast='infer').mul(N)
```

Output:

```
         time    name  value
0  01/01/2023  DE_STC      1
1  02/01/2023  DE_STC      2
2  01/01/2023  FR_STC      0
3  02/01/2023  FR_STC      1
```